# Unable to connect to Heroku API

Tags: ruby, heroku

```
$ heroku git:remote -a quiet-scrubland-9526

Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... !    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and try again.
$ heroku status

/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:114: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/corwin/.rvm in PATH, mode 040777

Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... !    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and try again.
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: email@domain.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Authentication successful.
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Is "Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and try again." significant? Perhaps your DNS or their host connectivity is down?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is happening because either:

- Heroku is experiencing an outage (not likely),
- Your internet connection / DNS connection are no working (pretty likely).

The solution is just wait a bit and try again, hope this helps.